# A menu of Linux commands (e.g ls, ipconfig etc) that forks and uses execl to run the commands as a child process

Tags: c, menu, fork, pid, ls

I have been given some code and I need to adapt this to show a menu of Linux commands and when a command is selected, the program should fork and use execl to run the commands as a child process and show its PID. I'm new to C so this I've been struggling so far :/

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sys/types.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(){

pid_t pid;
    int status = 0;
    int i;
    pid= fork() ;
        if(pid!=0) {
                wait(&status);
                printf ( " I am the parent my PID is %d, myPPID is %d, \n ",getpid(),getppid());
                printf( "Mychild process has finished. \n ");
        }else {
        printf ( " I am the child , my PID is %d , my PPID is %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
        sleep(2);
        execl ( "/bin/ls",".",(char*)0);
        printf( "Can you read this ?\n " ) ;
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question for us?

Comment: How would I go about starting this off?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  Do you want to know about some kind of misbehavior of the code presented? (Which?)  Do you want to know how to program some specific operation? (What?)

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to understand how I'd go about getting the program to run the Linux commands when selected by the user from a menu.

Comment: Regarding: `printf( "Can you read this ?\n " ) ;`  The `exec*()` commands ONLY return if the `exec*()` function failed.  In such a failure the statements should be: `perror( "execl()` failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: The `fork()` function has three(3) kinds of return indications 1) >0 means in the parent process  2) ==0 means in the child process  and 3) <0 means a error occurred.  When the error occurs then execute: `perror( "fork failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `perror()` outputs to stderr, your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: regarding: `execl ( "/bin/ls",".",(char*)0)`   Rather than `(char*)0`  much better to use the predefined value `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

before calling

```
fork()
```

the code should display the menu, probably via some calls to printf(),

then input the users selection

then use that selection, probably via a `switch()` statement, to place the appropriate text into an

```
char *args[] variable
```

then use that `args[]` variable when calling `execl()`